# Instalar APK generada por Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, app

Estoy realizando una App desde Android Studio y se me dio por intentar descargar la aplicación e instalarla en mi celular aunque todavía no este finalizada. Por lo tanto fui a **Build > Generate Signed APK**, generé el archivo JAR y luego me creo mi APK. Hasta ahí sin problemas.

Pero cuando voy a  instalar mi App en el celular me dice que no se puede.

*Mi celular tiene una API 19 y en el Gradle la min SDK version es 15.*

---

Ya se soluciono, cuando hago Build > Generate Signed APK. se me genera un archivo app-release.apk. Pero cuando simplemente hago Build>Build APK. se me gener aun archivo app-debug.apk. Y ese si puedo instalarlo. Si alguien sabria explicarme la diferencia-

Comment: Permitiste en tu celular la instalación de aplicaciones de origen desconocido?

Comment: si, sino no me dejaba ni intentar instalarla.

Comment: Aclaro que instalandola a traves android studio por cable si puedo hacerlo.

Comment: Tienes que desintalar tu aplicación del telefono y luego instalar el apk nuevo

Comment: Creaste las claves para firmar tu apk en modo de producción?

Comment: no estoy seguro a que te referis, pero es cuando se te genera el archivo  jar, despues de colocar un usario y contraseña?

Comment: "Mi celular tiene una API 19 y en el Gradle la min SDK version es 15." **Esto no es un problema al contrario tu API es mayor que la minima versión definida que es 15.**

Comment: Ya lo se, pero para descartar que alguien me responda con eso.

Comment: Yo lo que hago cuando quiero probar una aplicación hecha en android studio es configurar mi celular en modo desarrollador, conecto el celular al computador con el cable de datos, espero a que lo reconozco y luego le doy run a la aplicación y espero a que se cargue. Ella queda instalada por defecto en el celular después de que me salga de ella.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ve a File > Build APK, una vez generada el apk aparecera un mensaje como este
[image: Una vez generada la apk aparece esto]

das click en "show in explorer", copias el apk a tu telefono y podras instalarlo sin problemas.

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que las apk se pueden generar en modo debug y en modo release, creo que la respuesta de @jorgesys explica mejor las posibilidades.

Answer (score 5):

> Por lo tanto fui a Build > Generate Signed APK, generé el archivo JAR
> y luego me creo mi APK.

Aunque el .jar y el .apk son archivos compresos de un paquete, el archivo adecuado para instalación es el que tiene extensión .apk

> Pero cuando voy a instalar mi App en el celular me dice que no se
> puede.

No especificas en que forma la tratas de instalar, si no es mediante el ADB y la instalas por medio de una descarga del .apk debes asegurar que tu dispositivo permita instalaciones de "origenes desconocidos" ("unknown sources").

> Mi celular tiene una API 19 y en el Gradle la min SDK version es 15.

" **Esto no es un problema al contrario tu API es mayor que la minima versión definida que es 15.**

> Ya se soluciono, cuando hago Build > Generate Signed APK. se me genera
> un archivo app-release.apk. Pero cuando simplemente hago Build>Build
> APK. se me gener aun archivo app-debug.apk. Y ese si puedo instalarlo.

Tanto una aplicación generada con un Keystore de producción como una generada con el de debug pueden ser instaladas en un dispositivo, si este permite instalación de "origen desconocido" y **algo importante es asegurar no tener instalada una versión de la aplicación ya que no permitira sobreescribirla por tener el mismo `versionCode`.**

#### .APK RELEASE

Si generas el .apk mediante :

`Build` > `Generate Signed APK`

el .apk generado estaría firmado con un keystore que supone ser para producción, el cual previamente se creo para este proposito. **Este .apk se consideraría el adecuado para subir a Google Play Store.**

#### .APK DEBUG

Si generas el .apk mediante:

```
Build APK
```

Se generaría un .apk firmado con el keystore de debug, que generalmente se encuentra en la ruta:

```
:\users\<usuario>\.android\debug.keystore
```

---

Aunque no generes tu .apk con las opciones anteriores, con el simple hecho de generar tu proyecto y subirlo al dispositivo, se crea un .apk el cual puedes usar para instalación y se encuentra en la ruta:

```
   <proyecto>\app\builds\outputs\apk\
```

Answer (score 4):

Si podías instalar al APK de debug sin problemas, pero la APK release no te permitía (aparecía el mensaje Aplicación no instalada), yo lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

Fui a Build / Generate Signed APK...

Como seguramente ya lo habías hecho, en el KeyStore Path te va a aparecer la key generada anteriormente.  Lo dejas así, y ponés los passwords que pusiste la primera vez q generaste la Signed APK.

Y en el siguiente, TILDAS TANTO "V1 (Jar Signature)" como "V2 (Full APK Signature)", y le das a Finish.

[image: Tildar ambas opciones V1 y V2]

Yo la primera vez q la creé, sólo tenía marcado con tilde la V2 y tenía el mismo problema.  Marqué ambas opciones, generé nuevamente la APK Release, y pude instalarla.

Y si es la primera vez q generás el APK Release, simplemente tilda ambas opciones cuando te aparecen.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me sucedió lo mismo, siempre y cuando generaba mi apk desde Build>Build APK. podía instalar y des-instalar la apk las veces que fuesen sin ningún problema, mas sin en cambio si generaba la Build > Generate Signed APK, al pasar la apk al teléfono e intentar instalarla solo me permitía una ocasión, misma en la que me salia el siguiente mensaje: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta ahí todo bien si seleccionaba "INSTALAR DE TODAS FORMAS", pero que pasaba si desinstalaba la app y quería volver a instalarla (un posible escenario), sucedía lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo que resolví el problema inhabilitando **play protect**, lo cuál logre (dentro de Google Play) > Menú > Play Protect > Buscar amenazas de seguridad (inhabilitar).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

1. No tienes que generar APK para probarlo en tu celular.
2. La diferencia es: release (compilado para publicar) debug (compilado de prueba). el debug no se puede subir al Google Play.
3. Si quieres probar tu App (en desarrollo) en tu celular haz lo siguiente:

   1. Activa modo desarrollador en tu celular (tambien lo llaman modo developer o  programador).
   2. Conecta tu celular a tu PC mediante cable USB.
   3. Probablemente aparezca una notificacion en tu celular en el cual debes permitir la "administración a traves de esa PC).
   4. Abre Android Studio (y espera a que gradle termine su trabajo)
   5. Ejecuta (run) tu aplicacion desde android studio.
   6. En lugar de elegir un emulador, elige tu celular
   7. Android Studio instalará la app en tu celular cada que lo ejecutes (run).